Using FromSql or FromSqlInterpolated
According to this documentation (https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql/from-sql) you should do this:
string value = "value";

_dbContext.Set<T>().FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%{value}%'");

Same result when I use a FormatableString:
FormatableString sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%{value}%'"
_dbContext.Set<T>().FromSqlInterpolated(sql);

After analysing the sql query as string the result is:
"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%{0}%'"

What am I missing or doing wrong? And when should you use FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated?

Either add the %s before you pass the string into the sql, or as an expression in sql '%'+{value}+'%'.

You could use FromSqlRaw with string and single quotation:
string value = "value";
string sql = $"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ColumnName LIKE = '%{value}%'";
_dbContext.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw(sql);

Or FromSql/FromSqlInterpolated with FormattableString and without single quotation:
string value = "%value%";
FormattableString sql = $"SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Title LIKE {value}";
_dbContext.Set<T>().FromSqlInterpolated(sql);


Don't use FromSqlRaw like this. An attacker could provide the string; '; drop table students --
